# how do i install microsoft office from usb

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, microsoft-office

I am new to Ubuntu and I have tried using **LibreOffice**, but I face a lot of problem using **LibreOffice Calc** instead of MS Excel.

Please help me get **MS Excel** back so I can do my work smoothly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to mention which version and installation media of microsoft office you have, in order to install MS Excel via wine. Moreover, what problems did you encounter in Libreoffice. Functionwise, there is very little that cant be done with Libreoffice. If you have particular file incompatibilities, then indeed Libreoffice might be no option. The easiest (but also most expensive) way to install MSOffice is via MS Windows virtual machine.

Comment: Consider the online web apps

Comment: You can try to install office in linux, but the results are not good. The best solution for me is use Excel online. If you have a outlook account, you can try it. The tools and the buttons are very similar to MS excel. The only problem is that is a online app, so if you have not internet connection, you can not edit or view your files.

Comment: Ms office is not the way to go. "lot of problem"  is too vague too. I would advice getting using to Calc and ask about problems you face and can't seem to fix yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't. MS Office only runs on Windows.**

You could *try* running it on WINE, but no guarantees.

WINE stands for **W**ine **I**s **N**ot an **E**mulator
It is a compatibility layer that allows running Win32 apps on Linux.

However, it is **FAR** from perfect. Many applications will will simply crash during install or on luanch.

---

You can install wine with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Then you can try installing office by double-clicking the setup EXE.

It will probably crash during install.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps-3-0.html), which is a third party wine wrapper and contains various scripts to install Microsoft Office on Linux.

[image: POL MSOffice]